# Gradient of this function

Tags: derivatives, optimization, normed-spaces, duality-theorems

I am to solve an optimization problem as described below:

$$ \min f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left\lVert x - x_{b} \right\rVert^{2}+ \frac{1}{2}\left\lVert \epsilon \right\rVert^{2}$$
with $$ Hx -y = \epsilon $$

If I'm to prove that the problem is convex, how do  I take the gradient two times of this function? I have problem derivating when there is a norm in it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Observe that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\|x\|^2  =\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2=\sum_{k=1}^n \underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}x_k^2}_{\substack{=0, \ \text{ if } j \neq k,\\=2x_j, \ \text{ else }}}= 2x_j$$
giving $$\nabla \|x\|^2 = 2x.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express the norm squared as inner products of vectors, leading to a quadratic form highlighted in blue below (I have assumed all the vectors have real components, so that for vectors $x$ and $y$, we have $x^Ty=y^Tx$)
$$\begin{align}f(x) &= \frac{1}{2}\left\lVert x - x_{b} \right\rVert^{2}+ \frac{1}{2}\left\lVert \epsilon \right\rVert^{2} \\&= \frac{1}{2}( x - x_{b})^T(x-x_b)+ \frac{1}{2}(Hx-y)^T(Hx-y)\\&=\frac{1}{2}(x^Tx\color{red}{-x^Tx_b-x_b^Tx}+x_b^Tx_b)+\frac{1}{2}(x^TH^THx\color{red}{-x^TH^Ty-y^THx}+y^Ty)\\&=\frac{1}{2}(\color{blue}{x^Tx}\color{red}{-2x_b^Tx}+x_b^Tx_b)+\frac{1}{2}(\color{blue}{x^TH^THx}\color{red}{-2y^THx}+y^Ty)
\\&=\frac{1}{2}\color{blue}{x^T(I+H^TH)x}-x_b^Tx+\frac{1}{2}x_b^Tx_b-y^TH^Tx+\frac{1}{2}y^Ty\end{align}$$
Using matrix calculus result $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}x^TAx=A+A^T$ , the second derivative is straightforward
$$f^{''}(x)=(I+H^TH)$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Hello and thank you. Can you describe how you go from the second line to the third line? I'm having trouble understanding. Thanks!

Comment: @Chirac I have added a few more steps between the second and third line. I hope this helps clarify.

Comment: You are welcome.